# ignore previous ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Code Updated

This is my js

destroy.js.erb

```
$('.delete_loop').on('ajax:success', function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
  var loopNumber = $('.form-loop-number').html()
  $('.form-loop-number').html(loopNumber - 1)
  });
```

my ajax is called with rails :remote => true helper

index.html.erb:

```
= link_to calendar_video_ad_schedule_path(schedule.id), method: :delete, :remote => true, data: { confirm: 'Êtes vous sûr ?' }, :class => 'delete_loop' do
    i.icon-trash style='color:grey; font-size: 1.2em'
```

When I delete an item I want the number of my .form-loop-number in the html to decrease. It works the 1st time, but if I call the method twice or more, the number decreases more than once.

1st time I remove item: loopNumber - 1

2nd time I remove item: loopNumber - 2

3rd time I remove item: loopNumber - 3

etc...

My controller responds sur js format

controller:

```
def destroy
  @schedule = Schedule::VideoAd.find(params[:id])
  @schedule.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
    end
end
```

I only want it to decrease 1 each time. How can I do this ?

Comment: where is the code `$('.delete_loop').on('ajax:success', function () {...});` located?

Comment: its located in a seperate js file: destroy.js.erb

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
$('.delete_loop').on('ajax:success', function () {
...
});
```

event assignment is inside the code invoked during "delete" operation. Every time you delete, you add a new 'ajax:success' event handler. All these event handlers are executed on subsequent "delete"s. Move the above event assignment inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
});
```

Comment: tried putting in:
$(document).ready(function() {
...
});

still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the global ajax:success event handler, try using the success handler for your specific ajax call. I can't see the rest of your code, but if there's any other ajax it could be hitting this handler.

```
function deleteMyStuff(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/delete-my-stuff/',
        success: function(response) {
            $('.delete_loop').closest('tr').fadeOut();
            var loopNumber = $('.form-loop-number').html();
            $('.form-loop-number').html(loopNumber - 1);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Also, from the docs: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxSuccess() method should only be attached to document.

So attaching it to the .delete_loop element could be causing unwanted behavior.

Comment: I updated my code. I tried out your code and the function is not initialized. BTW i am using rails 3.

Comment: I'm seeing the code was updated...but that's ruby and js mixed together now...you may want to clean that up.  What function is not initialized?  Can you just show what's calling the ajax request?  Can you also just paste in the original ajax request code?

Comment: I pasted it in index.html.erb. I'm calling ajax with form_for and :remote => true helper.

Comment: Igor probably has the right answer above; I didn't realize this was all being generated by rails. I might look into it more if I have time, but I have no working knowledge of how rails generates ajax.

Comment: Is there a way to unbind previous ajax calls ?